# LIMIT and OFFSET in Subquery for MonetDB Alternative

Tags: sql, monetdb

So I am trying to execute the following statement in MonetDB:

```
SELECT AVG(col0), VAR_SAMP(col0) FROM (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 4 OFFSET 6) as foo;
```

I know that this is not supported in MonetDB, but I was wondering whether anyone had an alternative.

Thank you! I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm confused.  According to MonetDB documentation, `VAR_SAMP()` is supported as is `LIMIT . . . OFFSET`.  (https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/StatisticFunctions and https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference/TableExpressions)

Comment: Hey! LIMIT and OFFSET are apparently not supported in Subqueries - I get this error when I run this exact query:  `syntax error, unexpected LIMIT, expecting UNION or EXCEPT or INTERSECT or ')' in: "select avg(col0), var_samp(col0) from (select * from table limit"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem!

```
SELECT AVG(col0) FROM (SELECT col0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rnum FROM table) as foo WHERE rnum > 6 AND rnum < 11;
```

I can use a script to alter the rnum parameters and get the behavior I want.

Thanks!